# date formatter giving wrong dates in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I had an application in which i am using a date formatter for a string like 
"`6/30/2016 1:00:00 PM`" like this `30-Jun-2016 1:00`.I am doing like this

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm"];
NSString *stringDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
return stringDate;
```

but it is not giving me wrong date like this 30-Jan-2016 1:00 .

can anybody point me where i am going wrong ?

Comment: Your question is not understandable.

Comment: Use this date format in 2nd line MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a. I am getting 30-Jun-2016 01:00 as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given the wrong date format you need to capitalize month `MM` not small, small `mm` is for minute. Change your code like this.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm"];
NSString *stringDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
return stringDate;
```

Hope this will help you.